How does replication work when there are multiple racks in a DC?
I would like to understand how  Replication Factor works when having the following scenario:
We have a set of total of 18 disks, each one related to 1 Cassandra node, and all distributed in 3 Racks
Something like this:
|RACK1| |RACK2| |RACK3|
|node1| |node7| |node13|
|node2| |node8| |node14|
|node3| |node9| |node15|
|node4| |node10| |node16|
|node5| |node11| |node17
|node6| |node12| |node18|

We have a table with RF=3
When using a single rack, the data is replicated 3 times inside the nodes of that single rack.
But how does it work when having 3 different racks? What we would like to accomplish is that the data is replicated across racks instead of across the nodes of the same rack. For example, data1 is in node1, node7 and node13, data2 is in node2, node7 and node16, and so on. In other words: All data is located in each rack, rack1 has all data, and the same for rack2 and rack3. Does Cassandra work like this? is there a way to make Cassandra Replication Factor work across Racks instead of nodes?
We would like to accomplish this because each one of our racks is associated to 1 server, so if one server goes down, we would like to not lose data in the cluster, having all data replicated two times across the other two servers.
We already know how replication factor works when using a single rack.

It depends on the replication strategy configured on the keyspace.
With SimpleStrategy, Cassandra doesn't care about about the topology so all nodes are considered to belong to one giant ring regardless of rack or data centre configuration. Nodes are placed on one ring based on the token(s) they own and Cassandra places a copy of the data on the next node in the ring (replica).
For this reason, we recommend you always configure application [and authentication] keyspaces to use NetworkTopologyStrategy. With NTS, Cassandra is both rack-aware and DC-aware.
With NetworkTopologyStrategy, each DC is a single ring that contains a full copy of the data. When there is more than one rack configured, Cassandra will place copies (pick replicas) on the next node in the ring that is on a different rack than the previous replica.
In your case where replication factor is 3 and there are 3 racks in the DC, each rack will contain a full copy of the data.
For more info, see Data replication in Cassandra. Cheers!

Thank you!
So in my use case, would it work if I use NetworkTopologyStrategy and declare each server as a different datacenter? each datacenter with RF=1. Would that simulate a RF-3 across my three servers and their disks?

No, that's a bad idea.
